# How to install Mac buttons and scrollbars on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, themes, customization

I recently installed the mac theme for Ubuntu 12.10 from Noobslab. The installation went properly and I am now running the Mac theme. But I still don't have the scrollbars and buttons for Mac. This is how I would want my complete Mac theme to look like.

> [image]

Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: As far as scrollbars are concerned have you removed `overlay-scrollbars` ?

Comment: Yeah I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing following command in terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

It should fix scrollbars to the *normal* mode.

Anyway, I think you **won't** get MacOS-like scrollbars and buttons, because it looks like they are not included in theme from noobslab *(if you are using [this](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-mac-os-x-theme-on-ubuntu-1210.html) theme)*.

Comment: I have already switched to overlay scroll bars. But i wanted to use the Mac buttons and scroll bars! :/